# Show WordPress Page outside loop with vc page builder code inside the content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, visual-composer

I use WordPress inside an extern website
(with `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');`)

I would like to load a specific page and show the content.

```
$post = get_post(467, OBJECT);

$content = $post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('wpautop', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
setup_postdata($post);
```

...

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="entry-content">
    <?php echo $content; ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array(
                        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'tm-polygon' ),
                        'after'  => '</div>',
                        ) );
    ?>
  </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

...

The problem is: The page content is build by the visual composer page builder plugin and the output is plain vc code, instead of rendering the content.

Like: `[vc_row full_width="stretch_row" css=".vc_custom_1472216323117{margin-top: 0px !important;margin-bottom: 50px !important;padding-top: 170px !important;padding-bottom: 165px !important;background-image: url(http://wp.netzexperten.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/section14.jpg?id=469) !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}"][vc_column][vc_column_text el_class="section-title" css=".vc_custom_1443428582908{margin-top: -25px !important;margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"]`

I hope you can help me, chris

Answer (score 4):

Got it work:

```
WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

To register the VC shortcodes the following must be called:

`WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();`

Answer (score 3):

Please Try This

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $post->post_content ); ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $yourpostid)); ?>
```

Comment: thx for your quick response. But this will output the same not rendered visual composer code

Comment: I create a new shortcode via functions.php and added the new shortcode to the page. the new shortcode will be rendered correctly. only the vc shortcodes remain plain text.